# Discord.js user isnt mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a problem with sending messages when a user is tagged or not, I'm working on the pp command (as in dankmemer) but after adding the code so that I can tag a person the bot crashes, what I mean is that after tagging a person it will send a message in the title it will say the user's penis and if he is not tagged it will say the author,
code below :)

```
if (message.content === `${prefix}4fpp`) {
var facts = ["<====8", "<=====8","<=====8","<=======8",] 
var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
const pp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`${message.author.username} , penis:`)
.setDescription(facts[fact])
.setColor(`${GREEN}`)
.setFooter(`Commmand executed by: ${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
.setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(pp);
}
```

Comment: The code works for me assuming you have `GREEN` defined elsewhere. What errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: @APartOfMe const GREEN = '#15F00D'; and I have no error because there is no code, and I'm just asking for help, unfortunately I deleted that code, but I think I did it wrong, very wrong, so I'm waiting for someone to add to mine code :D

Comment: @APartOfMe There is only this code above and there are no errors, but the mention does not work

Comment: @KapiZiom404_ so the problem you have is that you want it to show pp size for mentioned user if there is a mentioned user and show pp size for the message author if there isnt a mentioned user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a mentioned user by using `message.mentions.users.first()`(read more about it in the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)). You can use that to format the embed properly by doing something like:

```
    const facts = ["<====8", "<=====8", "<=====8", "<=======8"];

    const fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);

    //Gets the first mentioned user
    const mention = message.mentions.users.first();

    const pp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(facts[fact])
        .setColor(GREEN)
        .setFooter(`Commmand executed by: ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.avatarURL())
        .setTimestamp();

    if (mention) { //Set the title to the mentioned user's username if applicable
        pp.setTitle(`${mention.username} , penis:`);
    } else { //Otherwise set it to the message author
        pp.setTitle(`${message.author.username} , penis:`);
    };

    message.channel.send(pp);
```

Comment: (node:35248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: `facts.length` is definitely defined. The code above worked for me. Are you sure you're defining the array correctly?

Comment: I used `msg` when testing, and I just realized that I forgot to change one of them back to `message` when posting the answer. I've updated my code. Check your code to make sure you use only `message`, since that's what you chose to use

Comment: bot still doesn't write back after tagging a person :C, It works only when I write without marking and I mean to mark people and send with their nickname and if not marked, with the author's nickname